# solr geodist() giving wrong distance

Tags: lucene, solrj

I am using geodist() in solr query. following is my query

```
q=(name:(*)&fl=person_id, name, longitude, lattitude, distance:geodist()&fq={!geofilt}&spatial=true&pt=73.7708441,18.5664871&d=10&sort=geodist() asc&group=true&group.field=person_id&group.format=simple&group.main=true&start=0&rows=15
```

one of entry in my output is

```
{
    \"personId\": 313403,
    \"name\": \"Dev\",
    \"longitude\": 73.812498,
    \"latitude\": 18.439598,
    \"distance\": 6.079763395151475,
}
```

But when I count distance between both lat long on internet i.e (73.7708441,18.5664871) to (73.812498, 18.439598), It gives me 14.782 km or 9.187 in mile

I searched about solr geodist() but same function and query is used everywhere. Can somebody please tell me whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved.

There were too mistake

1-pt should be `pt=lat, long`

2-while putting lat long in solr (by data-config.xml), name of latitude field should be `location_0_coordinate` and longitude - `location_1_coordinate`

in my case it was interchanged

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some wires have got crossed somewhere.

If your coordinates should be: (lat: 73.7..., long:18.5...), then solr's distance is correct, and your fields ("latitude" and "longitude") appear to be mislabelled

On the other hand, if it should be (lat: 18.5..., long:73.7...), then the distance you've calculated is correct, and the coordinates are backward in your query, which should be:  `pt=18.5664871,73.7708441`.  Pretty sure your `LatLonType` field would also have to have it backward, so those would need to be fixed and reindexed, as well.

Comment: yes I corrected It, pt should be (lat, long). And I had assigned lattitude to location_1_coordinate where it should be location_0_coordinate.

Anyways thanks for your comment